# How to set minimum date in jsDatepick?

Tags: javascript

I am using [jsDatepick](http://javascriptcalendar.org/javascript-date-picker.php). I need to set minimum date as today's date. Is there any option for this?

Comment: Have you checked it's document?

Answer (score 1):

A quick change to the code of JsDatePick will accomplish this. It's around line 671 in the full js file

It says if ( ! this.oConfiguration.limitToToday){

Just take out the !

i.e.

if (this.oConfiguration.limitToToday){

Answer (score 1):

Whenever u get any date selected you fire function 
where you will compare date..

Isn't it?